# What does 荠麦之茂，荠麦之有 in 《猗兰操》 mean? 韩愈《猗兰操》“荠麦之茂，荠麦之有”一句作何解释？

Tags: meaning-in-context, classical-chinese, poetry

This question is about understanding a verse in a poem by Han Yu of the Tang dynasty.

请问韩愈《猗兰操》里“荠麦之茂，荠麦之有”一句作何解释？

此句下一句，即全诗末句，“君子之伤，君子之守”，“言君子居可伤之时，故君子有可见之操守”；那么“荠麦”的比喻，是否是说荠麦茂于雪霜之时，方见其坚强之节操？

《详注韩昌黎诗集》中解释“荠麦之有”，曰：“谓荠麦之因有也。”这个“因有”又是什么意思呢？

Answer (score 10, accepted):

薺麥之茂，薺麥之有。
薺麥之茂生，薺麥之因有。
薺麥之茂生，因薺麥之有。
薺麥茂於雪霜之時，乃因薺麥之內有。
薺麥能茂生於雪霜之時，乃因薺麥之內在本有。
The buckwheat(?) can grow well in the snow because of its inherent ability.

君子之傷，君子之守。
君子之傷厄，君子之見守。
君子之傷厄，見君子之守。
君子居於艱難之境，方見君子之內守。
君子能安居於艱難之境，方見君子之內在操守。
A gentleman can live well in the predicaments, then people can see his inner integrity.

Comment: I think vuluvsa has answered the question. If you analyze the differences between the sentences, you will see the answers. ......因有 = 因......有. This answered the meaning of 因有. 有 = 內在本有. This answered that it's not 坚强之节操. This is an advanced question. So, vuluvsa gave an advanced answer.

Answer (score 2):

薺麥之**茂** -> 薺麥的**茂盛** -> The **lushness** of chestnut wheat

薺麥之**有** -> (來自)薺麥的**內在**(飽滿)。-> (comes from) chestnut wheat's **inside**(plumpness)

君子之**傷** -> 君子**的困苦** ->  a gentleman's **hardship**

君子之**守** -> (彰顯)君子的**操守** -> (emphasize) a gentleman's **integrity**

> 薺麥之茂，薺麥之有。"The lushness of chestnut wheat comes from their inner plumpness," 
>   (substance)
>
> 君子之傷，君子之守。"A gentleman shows his personal integrity during hardship."

*"Chestnut wheat has substance. Therefore, they are lush outside; a gentleman has substance. Therefore, he shows integrity during hardship."

> 《详注韩昌黎诗集》中解释“荠麦之有”，曰：“谓荠麦之因有也。”这个“因有”又是什么意思呢？

因 = cause; reason

因有 = there's cause /reason

荠麦之因有也 = there's reason within the chestnut wheat (it has substance)